# i need to destroy all of one type of block in the world (not just a small part)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

i had this amazing skyblock map until someone /fill barrier block all over i need to get rid of all of it with 1 command please help[image]

[image]

Comment: In your situation I would probably just put a command like `/execute at @a run fill ~-10 ~-10 ~-10 ~10 ~10 ~10 air replace barrier` into a repeating command block and then fly around in the affected area. Would that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Shouldn't /replace near work?

Comment: @Robbie I haven't heard of a `/replace near` command before, are you talking about some mod?

Comment: I guess it is. I've used it on multiplayer servers before and assumed it was just a vanilla command.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use the /fill command

> /fill x y z x2 y2 z2 block block variant replace block2

block variant

It goes as follows:

x y z - the coordinates of the bottom left area of where the barriers you want to replace are

x2 y2 z2 - the coordinates of the top right area of where the barriers you want to replace are

block - This is the type of block you want to replace e.g. Minecraft:barriers

block variant - In this case you don't need to use this. This would be used if you wanted to replace planks or logs

block2 - The block you want to replace the barriers with e.g. Minecraft:air

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please don't answer duplicate questions.